# How to access masOS apache localhost from other devices on lan?

Tags: macos, osx-server, apache

I have MBP with masOS Sierra. I’ve configured Apache server and mysql. I’m not using xampp or some other tool. I want to access my localhost on my iPhone. I’ve tried many different ways mostly describing getting local ip of my MBP and using it in iPhone browser but nothing is working for me. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Check https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11238

Comment: This shows how to setup localhost not how to access it on LAN e.g mobile device